# A factorization for operators

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras

Let   $a$ be an arbitrary operator in $B(H)$ and $b$ be  a positive operator in $B(H)$. Assume $a$ and $b$ have the same null space and  there exists an operator  $u\in B(H)$ with $a=ub$.

Q) Can we conclude the null space of $u$ is contained in the null space of  $a$?

Comment: Q1: no, we cannot (e.g. take $u = id$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $b $ to be a nontrivial projection, $u $ a unitary, and $a=ub $. Then $\ker a\ne\ker u=\{0\} $.

For Q2, take $a=u=b $.

Comment: Your are completely right. Actually, something was missed and I made correction. Please take a look at.

Comment: You can still take $a=b$ a projection, and $u$ the identity.

Comment: Thanks Martin, What about this version: $a\in B(H)$ and $0\leq b\in B(H)$. Assume there exists $c\in B(H)$ with $a=cb$. If Ker($b$) is contained in Ker($c$) then, can we conclude $b$ and $c$ have the same kernel?

Comment: No, even if all three are positive. Take $b $ a projection, and $a=c $ a proper subprojection.

Comment: Dear Martin, i think the previous example does not work. Please note that $b$ is a positive operator which has the same null space as arbitrary operator $a$ and $a=cb$ with Ker$(b)$=Ker$(a)\subseteq$ Ker$(c)$.  Do we have then  Ker$(b)$=Ker$(a)=$ Ker$(c)$?

Comment: No. Take $p$ a proper projection, put $a=b=p$, and $c=1$.